# Android RecyclerView shows nothing

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I want to make an Android application for my school. It should display the absence from the teacher and the menu, but the menu doesn't display anything. It doesn't give an exception or anything I can work with. I'm getting the data from a url with JSON data. Unfortunately I can't give you the url because of personal reasons.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkGBA.png)

Unfortunately it looks like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pyVM.png)

I have researched many pages trying to solve the problem myself, but it wasn't very helpfully. I'm using two RecyclerViews, two adapter classes and 2 fragments. It worked fine before I've implemented the http requests and the JSON parser. Can someone help me at this?

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragAbsenz fragAbsenz = new FragAbsenz();
    android.app.FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentLayout, fragAbsenz, 
    fragAbsenz.getTag()).commit();
    setTitle("Lehrerabsenzen");
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) 
   findViewById(R.id.navigation);




  navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
    (mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    MainActivity.context = getApplicationContext();
}

public static Context getAppContext() {
    return MainActivity.context;
}

FragAbsenz.java: (I haven't implemented the http request and the JSON 
parser on this one yet, but it only displays the first Item from 20 and 
the others are gone.)

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag_absenz, 
container, false);

    mRecycler = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_absenz);
    mContacts = new ArrayList<>();
    mContacts.add("Michi \n Zi");
    mContacts.add("Michi Zi 2");
    mContacts.add("Michi \n Zi 3");

    for (int i = 4; i < 20; i++) {
        mContacts.add("Michi Zi" + i);
    }

    mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mAdapter = new Abse_MainAdapter(mContacts);
    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return view;
}
```

Abse_MainAdapter.java:

```
class Abse_MainAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<Abse_MainAdapter.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<String> mContacts;

public Abse_MainAdapter(ArrayList<String> Contacts) {
    mContacts = Contacts;
}

@Override
public Abse_MainAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, 
int viewType) {
    View view = 
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.abse_row, 
parent, false);
    return new Abse_MainAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Abse_MainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int 
position) {
    holder.mFullName.setText(mContacts.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mContacts.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView mFullName;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mFullName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.full_name);
    }
}
```

FragMenu.java:

```
public class FragMenu extends Fragment {

ArrayList<String> mMenu;

RecyclerView mRv;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLm;
RecyclerView.Adapter mAd;

StringRequest stringRequest = null;
String result;

public FragMenu() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag_menu, 
container, false);

    mRv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_menu);

    RequestQueue queue = 
Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.getAppContext());
    String url = "Censored because of personal reasons";

    stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    result = response.substring(0);

                    try {
                        JSONObject JSONobj = new JSONObject(result);

                        String lastUpdate = 
JSONobj.getString("lastUpdate");
                        result = lastUpdate;

                        JSONArray WMenu = JSONobj.getJSONArray("data");

                        mMenu = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < WMenu.length(); i++) {
                            String Str = "";
                            JSONObject TMenu = WMenu.getJSONObject(i);
                            Str = Str + TMenu.getString("time") + "|";

                            JSONArray Menu = 
TMenu.getJSONArray("main");
                            String str = "";
                            for (int k = 0; k < Menu.length(); k++) {
                                str = str + Menu.getString(k) + "\n";
                            }
                            Str = Str + str + "|";

                            str = "";
                            JSONArray Hit = TMenu.getJSONArray("hit");
                            for (int k = 0; k < Menu.length(); k++) {
                                str = str + Hit.getString(k) + " \n";

                            }
                            Str = Str + str;

                            mMenu.add(Str);
                        }

                        mRv.setHasFixedSize(true);
                        mLm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                        mAd = new Menu_MainAdapter(mMenu);
                        mRv.setLayoutManager(mLm);
                        mRv.setAdapter(mAd);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //mText.setText("That didn't work!");
        }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);

    return view;
}



Menu_MainAdapter.java:

class Menu_MainAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<Menu_MainAdapter.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<String> mMenu;

public Menu_MainAdapter(ArrayList<String> Menu) {

    mMenu = Menu;
}

@Override
public Menu_MainAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, 
int viewType) {
    View view = 
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menu_row, 
parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Menu_MainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int 
position) {

    String date = ((mMenu.get(position)).split("|"))[0];
    String Menu = ((mMenu.get(position)).split("|"))[1];
    String Hit = ((mMenu.get(position)).split("|"))[2];

    holder.tDate.setText(date);
    holder.tDate.setText(Menu);
    holder.tDate.setText(Hit);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mMenu.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView tDate;
    public TextView tMenu;
    public TextView tHit;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tDate);
        tMenu = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu);
        tHit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hit);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="systems.exygen.examp.MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_frag_absenz.xml:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="systems.exygen.examp.FragAbsenz">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rv_absenz">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

abse_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="12dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/full_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_frag_menu.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="systems.exygen.examp.FragMenu">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rv_menu">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</FrameLayout>
```

menu_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tDate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Time"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:textSize="24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tages-Menü"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/menu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tages-Menü"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:textSize="16dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tages-Hit"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tages-Hit"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `abse_row.xml` your top-level tag is a `<LinearLayout>` that specifies `android:layout_height="match_parent"`. This will cause each item in your `RecyclerView` to be one screen tall; you should be able to see more cards if you scroll down.

Change that attr to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` instead and all should be good.

Comment: Thanks for your help.